# Why does PDO fetch() return only the first row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

When I select and print it, it shows only the first row, the query is the same. Why does it return only one row?

PHP Code:

```
$e = $db->query("SELECT `username`, `membership` FROM `users` WHERE `expire` != ''")->fetch();
print_r($e);
```

Result with PHP:

```
Array ( [username] => ItzBruney05 [0] => ItzBruney05 [membership] => 300 [1] => 300 )
```

Result when query is executed in phpMyAdmin:

[image]

Comment: Because `->fetch()` only fetches a single row. If you want all of the rows, do `->fetchAll()`.

Comment: A quick glance at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) would have answered this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's a good idea to read the documentation for a command when it returns an error or does not behave the way you expect it to.  Please do that before posting a question here.  Tip: the "see also" section for many commands often lists similar commands that might do what you want.  Also read user comments if the web documentation includes them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To select all rows using PDO, you need to use `fetchAll()` instead of `fetch()`.

```
$e = $db->query("SELECT `username`, `membership` FROM `users` WHERE `expire` != ''")->fetchAll();
```

In PDO, [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns "*the next row from a result set*".

[`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns "*an array containing all of the result set rows*".